# java.io.IOException: Alias name does not identify a key entry

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, tls1.2

I am trying to import an existing TLS certificate into a Spring boot application. I have performed several steps like trying to use .pfx file, cet file, and crt file but unfortunately I was not able to achieve the desired output. I am mentioning the steps that I have taken:

1. `openssl pkcs12 -export -in /sftpdrive/opt/ssl/rovermdwc/rovermd.com_ssl_certificate.cer -inkey /sftpdrive/opt/ssl/rovermdwc/_.rovermd.com_private_key.key -name rovermd.com -out rovermd.com.pfx`
2. `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore rovermd.com.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore rovermd.com.jks -deststoretype JKS`
3. `keytool -export -alias rovermd.com -keystore rovermd.com.jks -file rovermd.com.pem`
4. `keytool -import -alias rovermd.com -file rovermd.com.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass asdfghjkl`
5. `keytool -importcert -alias rovermd.com -file /sftpdrive/opt/SpringBoot/wildcard_rovermd_com.crt -keystore eps.p12 -storetype PKCS12`
6. `openssl pkcs12 -in /sftpdrive/opt/ssl/rovermdwc/_.rovermd.com_private_key.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out rovermd.crt`
7. `keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass Gm%EO5PatxcC -destkeystore mdrover.jks -srckeystore mdrover.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12`

Also, my spring boot application.properties contains:

```
# The path to the key store that holds the SSL certificate (a jks or p12 file).
#server.ssl.key-store= classpath:EPSWebhookApp.p12
server.ssl.key-store= /sftpdrive/opt/SpringBoot/mdrover.jks
# The password used to access the key store.
server.ssl.key-store-password= Gm%EO5PatxcC
# The type of the key store.
server.ssl.key-store-type= PKCS12
# The alias that identifies the key in the key store.
server.ssl.key-alias= mdrover
# The password used to access the key in the key store.
#server.ssl.key-password= asdfghjkl
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

If I use a self-signed certificate, it says that the certificate is invalid. Attaching the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Could anyone suggest what I am missing over here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *server.ssl.key-alias= mdrover* No alias in your console commands has that value. They are all 'rovermd.com'

Comment: actually, i have tried so many variants of properties in application.properties that I forgot to change over here. I have tried that combination and the error is same.

Comment: What happens when you `-list` the keystores with `keytool`?

Comment: You'll have to import the self signed certificate on the client cert store before you can use it. Trust needs to be established beforehand, obviously, otherwise anybody can use a self signed certificate and perform a MITM.

Comment: @g00se I can see the listing of self-signed certificates.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, actually this is a Webhook API and there will be no interface for this API. What I found out is that it needs to be installed on my environment. I was able to install a new certificate on my local machine. Now, trying to install it on a Linux environment.

Comment: But my question remains the same. If I am trying to re-import my existing certificate, I am still getting this error.

Comment: *@g00se I can see the listing of self-signed certificates* But what about the aliases? Is the correct cert under alias `rovermd.com`?

Comment: Yup, all are absolutely correct. The other day I found out that to import the existing TLS certificate, you need to keep the alias name same. Like for the one that I am creating on top of the existing one. I was trying to find the link to that webpage but couldn't find it.